# backbone.js for large applications

Tags: web-applications, backbone.js, scalability

I’m currently reading up on Backbone.js to dig into this nice, light-weight framework, but also to decide whether this is the way to go for me in some future projects I have on the drawing board. One thing I always seem to run into when reading about Backbone is that it is a framework mainly created and used for small (or smaller) sized web applications, such as the tutorial example, **todos**, on the Backbone.js official website.

I’m interested in learning about others' experience with Backbone.js and its scalability. Would one normally discourage the usage of Backbone.js for web-applications with a more complex structure and a lot more functionality than just a simple “todos” application and the like?

I’ve read some of the other questions on SO which provided me with some insights, but I still miss the “discussion” about this.

Every input will be highly appreciated.

Cheers,
- Mestika

Comment: Did you look at the examples? http://backbonejs.org/#examples  Also, as written, your question isn't a good fit for Stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're missing the point about the todomvc project which aims to demonstrate the usage of various JavaScript frameworks (including more full-featured frameworks such as [ember](http://emberjs.com/) and [Angular](http://angularjs.org/)) and allow comparison of the approach you would take using each.

The todo project was chosen as a fairly simple example which can still be used to demonstrate many of the core features of the various frameworks. If the example application was more complicated it would be less useful as a means of quick comparison.

Backbone, despite being quite light and non-proscriptive, can still be used as the basis of more complicated web applications, especially if you combine it with supporting libraries such as [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) (for modular JavaScript development) and [Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette) (composite application library for Backbone).

If you still need convincing, have a look at [this page](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Projects-and-Companies-using-Backbone) which lists some of the applications in the wild which are based on backbone.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer and for the link to the Backbone applications. I might missing the point for the Backbone Todos project so I'll try to investigate a bit further and especially for combining Backbone with other libraries. Thanks again

Comment: No bother Mestika. Good luck with your research!